# How to specify conditional constraints in CP-SAT

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I would like to add constraints of the form

a - b > 0 if c + d == 4

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling) talks about `OnlyEnforceIf` which I was hoping would allow

```
model.Add(a-b > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(c+d==4)
```

Unfortunately it seems OnlyEnforceIf can only take a single Boolean and not a condition such as c+d==4.  If I am reading the  documentation right it then goes on to suggest

```
model.Add(c+d==4).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
model.Add(c+d!=4).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())
model.Add(a-b > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
```

I have two questions:

1. Could someone explain the logic of this formulation please.  If the first conditions should be read "if b then c+d == 4. if not b then c+d != 4. if b then a-b > 0" then the logic doesn't seem the right way round. I want the constraint to be that a-b>0 if c+d==4 so surely it would be "if c+d==4 then b" shouldn't?.
2. I have a lot of these constraints I need to impose so it seems I will need to create a lot of new variables. I notice that in CPLEX for example you can specify if-then directly without creating a new variable.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let's decompose `(c+d == 4) <=> b`

   1. `b => (c+d == 4)` is added with `model.Add(c+d==4).OnlyEnforceIf(b)`
   2. `(c+d == 4) => b`'s [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) is `not(b) => not(c+d == 4)` and that is modeled with `model.Add(c+d!=4).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())`
2. The ortools philosophy is that they do not want to create variables under the hood as CPLEX does. [Reference](https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/Z2Q0m8gNadc/m/T_5J71JSBwAJ)

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you an ortools developer?

Comment: Sadly no, but Laurent has answered the second point in other forums, I'll add a reference if I find it